# Update notice with no details

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

Have been receiving update notices periodically for a couple of weeks, but there are no details about the update provided.  Haven't installed/applied it, so it continues to come up.  18.04.1LTS.

[image: screenshot of update]

response to suggestion of trying dry-run update (very long):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-eunit erlang-os-mon erlang-snmp fonts-unfonts-core fonts-wqy-microhei
  libaudiofile1 libcryptui0a libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libqt4-designer
  libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic plainbox-secure-policy
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-blinker python-dirspec python-jwt
  python-oauthlib python-olefile python-pil python-piston-mini-client
  python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip python3-checkbox-ng
  python3-checkbox-support python3-guacamole python3-jinja2 python3-padme
  python3-piston-mini-client python3-plainbox python3-xlsxwriter
  seahorse-daemon software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  clamav
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk appstream apt-config-icons binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bolt cpp cpp-7 evolution evolution-common
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins
  fonts-liberation fonts-opensymbol g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base gcc-8-base
  gdm3 ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 ipxe-qemu
  lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libappstream4 libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libcamel-1.2-61 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcuda1-340 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25
  libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-23 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libegl1
  libevolution libgcc-7-dev libgcc1 libgdm1 libgfortran4 libgl1 libgles2
  libglvnd0 libglx0 libgomp1 libgs9 libgs9-common libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2
  libnautilus-extension1a libplymouth4 libpython3.6 libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-stdlib libquadmath0 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-en-us
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans
  libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-galaxy
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer libstdc++-7-dev libstdc++6
  libtsan0 libubsan0 libudisks2-0 nautilus nautilus-data nvidia-340
  nvidia-opencl-icd-340 plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text plymouth-x11 python-apport python-problem-report
  python3-apport python3-distupgrade python3-problem-report python3-uno
  python3-update-manager python3.6 python3.6-minimal tzdata
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk udisks2 uno-libs3
  update-manager update-manager-core ure
119 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Inst libpython3.6 [3.6.5-3] (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst python3.6 [3.6.5-3] (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libpython3.6-stdlib [3.6.5-3] (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst python3.6-minimal [3.6.5-3] (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libpython3.6-minimal [3.6.5-3] (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst libtsan0 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst gcc-8-base [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libmpx2:amd64 lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libquadmath0:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 libstdc++6:amd64 ]
Conf gcc-8-base (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libmpx2:amd64 lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libquadmath0:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 libstdc++6:amd64 ]
Inst libstdc++6 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libmpx2:amd64 lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libquadmath0:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Conf libstdc++6 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libmpx2:amd64 lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libquadmath0:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst libquadmath0 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libmpx2:amd64 lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst libmpx2 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst liblsan0 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libitm1:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst libitm1 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst libgomp1 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 ]
Inst libcc1-0 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 libatomic1:amd64 ]
Inst libatomic1 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [lib32stdc++6:amd64 libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 ]
Inst lib32stdc++6 [8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libgcc1:amd64 lib32gcc1:amd64 ]
Inst lib32gcc1 [1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libgcc1:amd64 ]
Inst libgcc1 [1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2] (1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgcc1 (1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst tzdata [2018d-1] (2018e-0ubuntu0.18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [all])
Inst libplymouth4 [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst plymouth-x11 [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst plymouth-label [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst plymouth [0.9.3-1ubuntu7] (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk [1:18.04.25] (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst ubuntu-release-upgrader-core [1:18.04.25] (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst update-manager [1:18.04.11.4] (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst update-manager-core [1:18.04.11.4] (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst python3-distupgrade [1:18.04.25] (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst python3-update-manager [1:18.04.11.4] (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst python3-problem-report [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst python3-apport [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst apport [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst apport-gtk [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst libappstream4 [0.12.0-3] (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst appstream [0.12.0-3] (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst apt-config-icons [0.12.0-3] (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu [2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04] (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [binutils:amd64 ]
Inst libbinutils [2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04] (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [binutils:amd64 ]
Inst binutils [2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04] (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst binutils-common [2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04] (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst bolt [0.3-0ubuntu0.1] (0.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst libubsan0 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libasan4 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libcilkrts5 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst g++-7 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst gcc-7 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libstdc++-7-dev [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libgcc-7-dev [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libgfortran4 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst cpp-7 [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst gcc-7-base [7.3.0-16ubuntu3] (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst cpp [4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2] (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst evolution-data-server-common [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst libedataserverui-1.2-2 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst evolution-data-server [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libedata-cal-1.2-28 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libecal-1.2-19 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libebook-1.2-19 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libedata-book-1.2-25 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libebook-contacts-1.2-2 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libebackend-1.2-10 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libedataserver-1.2-23 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libcamel-1.2-61 [3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst evolution-plugin-pstimport [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst evolution-plugin-bogofilter [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libevolution [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst evolution-plugins [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst evolution [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst evolution-common [3.28.1-2] (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst fonts-liberation [1:1.07.4-5] (1:1.07.4-7~18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst fonts-opensymbol [2:102.10+LibO6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (2:102.10+LibO6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst gcc [4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2] (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst g++ [4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2] (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst gdm3 [3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4] (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libgdm1 [3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4] (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst gir1.2-gdm-1.0 [3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4] (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst ghostscript-x [9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.2] (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64]) []
Inst ghostscript [9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.2] (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64]) []
Inst libgs9 [9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.2] (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64]) []
Inst libgs9-common [9.22~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.2] (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [all])
Inst libudisks2-0 [2.7.6-3ubuntu0.1] (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Inst gir1.2-udisks-2.0 [2.7.6-3ubuntu0.1] (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Inst ipxe-qemu [1.0.0+git-20180124.fbe8c52d-0ubuntu2] (1.0.0+git-20180124.fbe8c52d-0ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst libcuda1-340 [340.106-0ubuntu3] (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst nautilus [1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4] (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst nautilus-data [1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4] (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst libnautilus-extension1a [1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4] (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst ure [6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst uno-libs3 [6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst libreoffice-calc [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-impress [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-draw [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-gnome [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-gtk3 [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst python3-uno [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-style-tango [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst libreoffice-style-breeze [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst libreoffice-pdfimport [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst libreoffice-common [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) [libreoffice-style-galaxy:amd64 ]
Inst libreoffice-style-galaxy [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst libreoffice-ogltrans [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-math [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-base-core [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libreoffice-writer:amd64 ]
Inst libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [libreoffice-writer:amd64 ]
Inst libreoffice-writer [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libreoffice-core [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst libreoffice-help-en-us [1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1] (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst libegl1 [1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1] (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libgl1 [1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1] (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libglx0 [1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1] (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libgles2 [1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1] (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libglvnd0 [1.0.0-2ubuntu2.1] (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst nvidia-340 [340.106-0ubuntu3] (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst nvidia-opencl-icd-340 [340.106-0ubuntu3] (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst python-problem-report [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst python-apport [2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2] (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Inst udisks2 [2.7.6-3ubuntu0.1] (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf libpython3.6 (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf python3.6 (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libpython3.6-stdlib (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf python3.6-minimal (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libpython3.6-minimal (3.6.6-1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libtsan0 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libquadmath0 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libmpx2 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf liblsan0 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libitm1 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgomp1 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libcc1-0 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libatomic1 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf lib32stdc++6 (8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf lib32gcc1 (1:8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf tzdata (2018e-0ubuntu0.18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [all])
Conf libplymouth4 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf plymouth-x11 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf plymouth-label (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf plymouth (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf update-manager (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf update-manager-core (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.26 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf python3-update-manager (1:18.04.11.5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf python3-problem-report (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf python3-apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf apport-gtk (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libappstream4 (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf appstream (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf apt-config-icons (0.12.0-3ubuntu1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libbinutils (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf binutils (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf binutils-common (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf bolt (0.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libubsan0 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libasan4 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libcilkrts5 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf g++-7 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf gcc-7 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libstdc++-7-dev (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgcc-7-dev (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgfortran4 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf cpp-7 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf gcc-7-base (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf cpp (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-data-server-common (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libedataserverui-1.2-2 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-data-server (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libedata-cal-1.2-28 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libecal-1.2-19 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libebook-1.2-19 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libedata-book-1.2-25 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libebook-contacts-1.2-2 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libebackend-1.2-10 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libedataserver-1.2-23 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libcamel-1.2-61 (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-plugin-pstimport (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-plugin-bogofilter (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libevolution (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-plugins (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf evolution-common (3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf fonts-liberation (1:1.07.4-7~18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf fonts-opensymbol (2:102.10+LibO6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf gcc (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf g++ (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf gdm3 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgdm1 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf ghostscript-x (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf ghostscript (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf libgs9 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf libgs9-common (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [all])
Conf libudisks2-0 (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf gir1.2-udisks-2.0 (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf ipxe-qemu (1.0.0+git-20180124.fbe8c52d-0ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libcuda1-340 (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf nautilus (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf nautilus-data (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libnautilus-extension1a (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf ure (6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf uno-libs3 (6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-calc (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-impress (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-draw (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-gnome (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-gtk3 (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf python3-uno (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-style-tango (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libreoffice-style-breeze (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libreoffice-pdfimport (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libreoffice-common (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libreoffice-style-galaxy (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libreoffice-ogltrans (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-math (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-base-core (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-writer (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-core (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libreoffice-help-en-us (1:6.0.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf libegl1 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgl1 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libglx0 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libgles2 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libglvnd0 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf nvidia-340 (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf nvidia-opencl-icd-340 (340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf python-problem-report (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf python-apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.4 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf udisks2 (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
```

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt upgrade --dry-run` ? It will not actually do the upgrade but will show you what would be changed.

Comment: Update your system and maybe the update will fix the problem.

Comment: next time it pops up, i'll let it do its thing.  checking from settings says it's up to date.  thanks.

Comment: ok, hadn't seen/recognized that one in the first few hundred questions.  thanks.

Comment: seems using the updater doesn't do the trick; had to use the apt-get upgrade commandline.